# can't use paratype font even after running updmap

Tags: fonts

I am trying to use a paratype font by putting the following into the preamble of my document:

```
\RequirePackage{paratype}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

This works fine on my work machine, but on my personal machine I am getting the following error message when I try to compile my document:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+340/600 --dpi 940 PTSans-Italic-tlf-t1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for PTSans-Italic-tlf-t1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps PTSans-Italic-tlf-t1--base is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
```

I have tried to fix this with `updmap` (I realize there are downsides to using `updmap-user` as opposed to `updmap-sys`; that is not what I care about at the moment however):

```
sudo updmap-user --force --enable Map=paratype-truetype.map
```

Here is the output from the above command:

```
updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /home/username) to root's actual home (/root).
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /root/.texlive2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg
  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
  /root/.texlive2017/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/root/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/root/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/root/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
updmap [WARNING]: font PTSans-Narrow-tlf-t1--base is defined multiple times:
updmap [WARNING]:   paratype-type1.map (from /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [WARNING]:   paratype-truetype.map (from /etc/texmf/web2c/updmap.cfg) (used)
... (ommitting many similar warnings) ...

updmap is creating new map files
using the following configuration:
  LW35 font names                  : URWkb (default)
  prefer outlines                  : true (default)
  texhash enabled                  : true
  download standard fonts (dvips)  : true (default)
  download standard fonts (pdftex) : true (default)
  jaEmbed replacement string       : noEmbed (default)
  jaVariant replacement string     : <empty> (default)
  scEmbed replacement string       : noEmbed (default)
  tcEmbed replacement string       : noEmbed (default)
  koEmbed replacement string       : noEmbed (default)
  create a mapfile for pxdvi       : false (default)

Scanning for LW35 support files  [  3 files]
Scanning for MixedMap entries    [ 50 files]
Scanning for KanjiMap entries    [ 11 files]
Scanning for Map entries         [265 files]

Generating output for dvipdfmx...
Generating output for ps2pk...
Generating output for dvips...
Generating output for pdftex...

Files generated:
  /root/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
       15786 2018-10-11 14:15:12 builtin35.map
       21259 2018-10-11 14:15:12 download35.map
     2445741 2018-10-11 14:15:12 psfonts_pk.map
     2706850 2018-10-11 14:15:12 psfonts_t1.map
     2700806 2018-10-11 14:15:12 ps2pk.map
          14 2018-10-11 14:15:14 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map
  /root/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
     2700813 2018-10-11 14:15:14 pdftex_dl14.map
     2699148 2018-10-11 14:15:13 pdftex_ndl14.map
          15 2018-10-11 14:15:14 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
  /root/.texlive2017/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap:
        6706 2018-10-11 14:15:12 kanjix.map

Transcript written on "/root/.texlive2017/texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log".
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

However when I go to look at the generated files in my file explorer it appears they have not been updated; the date on them is 9/27/2018. I am at a loss; many other answers I have looked at suggest that running `updmap` should fix this issue.

I will note that adding `\pdfmapfile{+paratype-truetype.map}` to the preamble of my document fixes the problem, but this is not a good permanent solution.

I am running Xubuntu 18.04, TexLive 2017.

Comment: `sudo updmap-user ` sounds odd. And it also sounds odd that the generated maps are in /root/. Where is the map-file located that your document actually use? Did you try simply `updmap-user`? (Disclaimer: I'm on windows).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I had not tried updmap-user without sudo. However, that did the trick. I have no idea why including sudo would make a difference, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The solution, which I got from Ulrike Fischer's comment, was to run

```
updmap-user --force --enable Map=paratype-truetype.map
```

I have no idea why including sudo would make a difference here. If anyone can provide any insight I would be very interested to learn!